# add VLAN access ports to a VSI (HP)

Tags: vlan, hp, vpls

I'm trying to understand how VLANs work in conjunction with VSI / VPLS. I'm using two HP A5800AF switches connected through MPLS.

Specifically, I want to associate a port on each side with a specific VSI (vpls_cf2) and configure that port in access mode with some VLAN (200). I then want to allow more ports in the same VLAN to see all other ports across the switches through the VSI.

For a single port the following works:

`display current-configuration interface GigabitEthernet1/0/34
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/34
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 200
 service-instance 1000
  encapsulation s-vid 200
  xconnect vsi vpls_cf2 access-mode ethernet
#`

However, I would have expected other ports in the same VLAN (200) to then be able to also "see" port 34. This doesn't seem to be the case unless I specifically add a service instance to them as well. Is there a better way to achieve this? Or will I have to configure each port individually? I can't really see the point of using a VLAN here if the VSI isolates the visibility anyway.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: If you add an access port in VLAN 300 to this VPLS VSI, will it see the VLAN 200 host? (If yes, I think it is indeed completely pointless) If no, try this : add two VLAN 300 hosts to this VPLS VSI will they see each other and be isolated from VLAN 200 hosts ?